# Imprimir boton si un valor esta vacio

Tags: php, html, mysql, mysqli

Tengo una tabla que muestra los registros de pedidos entregados, y para finalizar el registro hay un boton "Agregar remision" para guardar la remision en la base de datos. Quiero hacer que cuando la tabla recargue y si la remision tiene valor que ya no muestre el boton para adjuntar la remision.

Esta es mi consulta:

```
$consulta="SELECT * FROM registros where estado = 'entregado'";
$registros=mysqli_query($conexion,$consulta) or die ("Problemas con la consulta");
```

Y aqui es donde creo las filas de la tabla con los resultados de la consulta:

```
while ($reg=mysqli_fetch_array($registros))
        {
            $pu = toMoney($reg['pu']);
            $padd = toMoney($reg['padd']);
            $folio= $reg['id'];
            echo "<tr id='head' data-toggle='modal' data-id='$folio' data-target='#orderModal' style='background: #aaffb3; cursor: pointer;'>
                        <td>".$reg['hora']."</td>
                        <td>".$reg['cliente']."</td>
                        <td>".$reg['dir_obra']."<br/>".$reg['indicaciones']."</td>
                        <td>".$reg['fecha_entrega']."</td>
                        <td>".$reg['resistencia']." </td>
                        <td>".$reg['remision']." </td>
                        <td style='display:none;'>".$reg['m3']." </td>
                        <td style='display:none;'>".$reg['id']." </td>
                        <td style='display:none;'>".$reg['metodo_pago']." </td>
                        <td style='display:none;'>".$reg['fecha_registro']." </td>
                        <td style='display:none;'>".$pu." </td>
                        <td style='display:none;'>".$reg['tiro']." </td>
                        <td style='display:none;'>".$reg['ton']." </td>
                        <td style='display:none;'>".$reg['elem_colar']." </td>
                        <td style='display:none;'>".$reg['revenimiento']." </td>
                        <td style='display:none;'>".$reg['adicionales']." </td>
                        <td style='display:none;'>".$padd." </td>
                        <td>
                            <button class='btn btn-success btn-sm btnRemision' aria-label='Left Align' value='$folio'> Agregar remision</button>
                        </td>
                    </tr>";
        }
```

De antemano muchas gracias por sus comentarios.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usa la funcion `isset`

```
if (!isset($reg['remision'])){
    echo "<button class='btn btn-success btn-sm btnRemision' aria-label='Left Align' value='$folio'> Agregar remision</button>"
}
```

Comment: Me deja toda la columna vacia, cuando $reg['remision'] si tenga valor que omita el boton

Comment: Eso es que `$reg['remision']` tiene valor siempre.

Answer (score 1):

puedes intentar lo siguiente , si es que la variable **$reg['remision']** es la que tiene no debería tener el valor

```
while ($reg=mysqli_fetch_array($registros))
        {
            $pu = toMoney($reg['pu']);
            $padd = toMoney($reg['padd']);
            $folio= $reg['id'];
            $button = "";
            if (!isset($reg['remision'])){
                $button = "<button class='btn btn-success btn-sm btnRemision' aria-label='Left Align' value='$folio'> Agregar remision</button>";
            }

            echo "<tr id='head' data-toggle='modal' data-id='$folio' data-target='#orderModal' style='background: #aaffb3; cursor: pointer;'>
                        <td>".$reg['hora']."</td>
                        <td>".$reg['cliente']."</td>
                        <td>".$reg['dir_obra']."<br/>".$reg['indicaciones']."</td>
                        <td>".$reg['fecha_entrega']."</td>
                        <td>".$reg['resistencia']." </td>
                        <td>".$reg['remision']." </td>
                        <td style='display:none;'>".$reg['m3']." </td>
                        <td style='display:none;'>".$reg['id']." </td>
                        <td style='display:none;'>".$reg['metodo_pago']." </td>
                        <td style='display:none;'>".$reg['fecha_registro']." </td>
                        <td style='display:none;'>".$pu." </td>
                        <td style='display:none;'>".$reg['tiro']." </td>
                        <td style='display:none;'>".$reg['ton']." </td>
                        <td style='display:none;'>".$reg['elem_colar']." </td>
                        <td style='display:none;'>".$reg['revenimiento']." </td>
                        <td style='display:none;'>".$reg['adicionales']." </td>
                        <td style='display:none;'>".$padd." </td>
                        <td>
                            $button
                        </td>
                    </tr>";
        }
```